# AWS docker image python lambda unable to access /tmp folder files

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, docker-image

I have downloaded a file from s3 and stored to /tmp folder.

File1:(inside lambda_handler)

```
    print("connecting to s3 bucket")
    bucket_db_name = os.environ['BUCKET_DB']
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    print("Getting ready to download 'data.h5s' file to local")
    s3.download_file(bucket_db_name, 'data.h5s', '/tmp/data.h5s') 
    print("file download complete")
```

i am trying to access the same from another function.But it throws OSError.
File 2 present as part of docker image file ,

```
try:
    with pd.HDFStore('/tmp/data.h5s', 'r') as h5s:
        old_data = h5s['data']
        h5s.close()
except EnvironmentError as e:
    print ('dB file problem. \nError:',e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the 'tmp' folder in your project and add the next line to your Dockerfile

```
ADD tmp ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/tmp
```